# Spring Rest @Controller works well with unobfuscated.jar but with obfuscated.jar returns 404 error

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations, obfuscation

I have written REST services using Spring-MVC's controller. To define controllers I have used annotations. All works well with unobfuscated jars. But with obfuscated jars it gives 404 in response.
I searched over net for any issue with obfuscation using RetroGuard and found that I need to preserve annotations after obfuscations. So I tried that too by setting "***.option Annotation***" but still it is not working.
Here is code

```
    @Controller
    public class ModelEntitiesController extends CommonExceptionHandler {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = -3097468664312037527L;

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @RequestMapping(value = "/Connections", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        @ResponseBody
        public ArrayList<ConnectionBean> getConnectionList() throws Exception {
               // creates an arraylist 
               return list;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's the point of obfuscating the jar of a webapp? I won't be downloaded by anyone and will stay on your web server.

Comment: Okay. But if I have to give it as a Jar to others, then I need to obfuscate it. I want to know is there any issue in resolving the request after obfuscation.

Comment: one usually don't make a webapp jar it and pass it on to others for use rather we deploy it on a server within a servlet container and giv access to app over network.

Comment: I think you're going to look at the obfuscated code to see what is occurring exactly.  If I remember right, some of the obfuscation tools will show you the java files prior to them being compiled.  Maybe the library is doing something else unexpected.  Best of luck.

Comment: But is there any way to do this with obfuscation ???

Comment: I think what you want to do is preserve the Controller's handler methods.  Who cares if they see the names of the handler methods.  I would think the most important part would be to obviscate from the service layers down.